# Compute average sales per day in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, average

In my database I have a table with two columns. The first column contains dates and the second is a count variable. I was wondering if it is possible to compute the average counts for each weekday based on the dates and counts. 
In the following a small example:

Table:

```
Date         Count
02/01/2005     100
02/02/2005     200
02/03/2005     300
...            ...
```

Output:

```
 Days       Average
 Monday       120.5         
 Tuesday      200.2                   
 Wednesday    300.5
```

Comment: First you need to group by `DAYNAME` and then try to convert row into columns using `MAX` and `GROUP BY`. You can google it as two different steps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could a series of [`avg`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_avg) calls on `case` expression extracting the day's name:

```
SELECT AVG(CASE DAYOFWEEK(`date`) WHEN 2 THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) AS Monday,
       AVG(CASE DAYOFWEEK(`date`) WHEN 3 THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) AS Tuesday,
       AVG(CASE DAYOFWEEK(`date`) WHEN 4 THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) AS Wednesday,
       AVG(CASE DAYOFWEEK(`date`) WHEN 5 THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) AS Thursday,
       AVG(CASE DAYOFWEEK(`date`) WHEN 6 THEN `count` ELSE NULL END) AS Friday
FROM   mytable
```

EDIT:
Given the updated expected output in the edited post, it's much easier to do - just group by the `dayname`:

```
SELECT   DAYNAME(`date`), AVG(`count`)
FROM     mytable
WHERE    DAYOFWEEK(`date`) BETWEEN 2 AND 6
GROUP BY DAYNAME(`date`)
```

Comment: Hi, that gave me syntax error. I'm sorry, I just recognized that I need the output in a different way... I edited my question. I tried something with Select Dayofweek(Date), AVG(Count) from table Group by Dayofweek(Date). However it didn't gave me the correct answer. Thanks for you reply!

Comment: @Peanut Yeah, I forgot the `end` there, and then just copy-pasted the mistake five times, my apologies. Given your latest update to the question, it's much easier to do - see my edited answer for the details.

Answer (score 0):

@Mureinik's answer also pivots the data sets. If you need the week days as rows, not columns (I'm not sure by your question), the query gets even easier (untested):

```
SELECT DAYNAME(`date`) AS day_of_week,
       AVG(`count`) AS average
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(`date`)
ORDER BY DAYOFWEEK(`date`)
```